# How to link Internal Pages in Jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

What to do if i want to link two internal pages on the click of a button using jquery or javascript...
i can do it using `<a href=#nextPage">` in HTML but i want a script to do it! what i am doing right now is:

```
<!-- first page-->
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Test page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>this page will link internal pages using # </p>
<a href="#nextPage" data-role="button">change to next page</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- second page-->
<div data-role="page" id="nextPage">
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Test page 2 </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<p>this page will  appear after you click the button on first page. </p>
</div>
</div>
```

this is doing good, but what i need is a script to link them. as in my app i need to change the page on click of button only after certain conditions met. but i dont know how to do it...

-----------Edit------------
I found out a way
window.location.href="#nextPage"
this is how its done. 
Thanks all for your effort..

Comment: You can add `onclick` event, or even better (?), you can attach the `.click` event.

Comment: i am doing it in my real app. but how to change the page????

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage` - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `onclick` handler to the `a` tag:

***JS***

```
function navigate() {
    if (condition) {
        $.mobile.changePage("#nextPage");
    }
}
```

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" onclick="navigate()" data-role="button">change to next page</a>
```

OR you can do this:

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-nextPage").click(function() {
        if (condition) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#nextPage");
        }
    });
});
```

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" class="nav-nextPage" data-role="button">change to next page</a>
```

Comment: $.mobile.changePage("#nextPage");
Not working!
nothing happens!

Comment: @priyankirk: If you are including jQuery Mobile, it should work. I tested with console, and I'm working on similar code right now.

Comment: Well idk, in simulator it is not working but in browser it is!!
anyways i found another way out
window.location.href="#nextPage";

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile, [Anatomy of a Page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html)

Scroll down to **Local, internal linked "pages"**

Comment: This is what i am exactly doing now.!
i need a script...
somthing like window.location and other stuff..